# Python interpreter version on windows

Tags: python, windows, version, interpreter

I am getting confused with all the different Python-interpreters (CPython, PyPy, etc.). Does anyone know what python-interpreter is used for the standard-python on Windows? I can't find it on [Official Python Website](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and when I type `py --version` in the command prompt it just tells me the python version (which is 3.6.0). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: There is no official "standard version" on Windows, which unlike many other OSs doesn't include one, so you must download and install it yourself. I believe most folks use the 32-bit version of CPython you can download from python.org.

Comment: I just downloaded it from the official website and started the installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from python.org is CPython.

You can also see the implementation from within Python by doing `import platform` and then `platform.python_implementation()`.  So you could get it from the command line with:

```
py -c "import platform; print(platform.python_implementation())"
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It not only correctly states that CPython is what is downloaded from python.org, but also how to programatically determine which implementation is being used in case one does not know where they downloaded python.

Answer (score 2):

The most common interpreter, which you downloaded from https://www.python.org/, is CPython. However, this interpreter is no standard; just commonly used. Python as a language is defined by the syntax, not interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the website link(python.org) you provided, if you install downloaded python from it, the interpreter is CPython, it is the most widely used implementation of python.

On windows machine, the python interpreter is usually installed  in `C:\Python36`, you can check it on the python shell by:

> sys.executable
>   A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, sys.executable will be an empty string or None.

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)
```

In my case, it returns `/Users/hzhang/.virtualenvs/env-3.5/bin/python`